# Web Server Directory / URL question

Tags: directory, url

Ok..So I know this is an easy question, but I just don't know. Given the URL:

```
http://mail.google.com/
```

What is mail? Is that a directory or what?

I have a domain, and I want to put a webpage on an address like this..how would I go about doing that?

I would like to have:

```
http://mypage.mydomain.com/
```

Comment: The particulars of actually doing this will depend upon your host and the control panel they offer. Check their knowledge base or contact support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a [subdomain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain). Depends on what your setup is in order to set one up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a subdomain but when you create them on your server there's still a actual folder storing the files or the subdomain just like you have files in a folder for your main website.

Most shared hosting sites let you create a folder using your control panel then set it to the root folder of your subdomain.